# call multiple argument function in applymap in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-applymap

I wrote a function for giving colors to the variables for pandas data frame.
there I used two arguments first one is variables list and another is threshold values list(i'am having only two values in the list e.g, say 30 and 50) for color the variables and function as follows::

```
def color_code(val,values):
    if val <= values[0]:
       color = 'green'
    elif values[0]<val<=values[1]:
       color = 'yellow'
    elif val >values[1]:
       color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

Now I want to call this function.For that i tried the following.

```
df1=df.style.applymap(color_code,subset=['col1','col2'],values=[30,50])
```

but the above call is not working for me.

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def color_code(values):
    def color_code_by_val(val):
        if val <= values[0]:
            color = 'green'
        elif values[0]<val<=values[1]:
            color = 'yellow'
        elif val >values[1]:
            color = 'red'
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    return color_code_by_val
```

Then your call should be:
`df1=df.style.applymap(color_code([30,50]), subset=['col1','col2'])`

Comment: if i want to use more than two arguments then i will use one more function with in the function right.

Comment: There is no need to create another function within it. You just need the color_code function to receive all the arguments that don't depend on the dataframe values. and the returned function should be getting only 1 argument.